# Is metric always quadratic?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

The derivation of metric tensor relies on infinitesimal displacements, which relies on Pythegoras theorem (a specific case of cosine law) to deduce that infinitesimal distance are related to the infinitesimal basis in qudratic form, and not in any other power.

Is metric necessary to be quadratic? It is deduced from Euclidean space, which may not be true for other general spaces. It seems tobe that metric not in quadratic form, like $ds$ or $ds^3$, can be possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say, but take a look at the $L^p$ norms, maybe it will help.

Comment: [The discrete metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html) does not really look quadratic to me.

Comment: Part of the issue here is the difference between a "metric on a vector space or manifold" and a distance function.

Comment: Try googling for "Finsler geometry", perhaps that's what you're after.